# Error code 70 while generating IPA with Phonegap build

Tags: ios, cordova, build, certificate, phonegap

I want to create an IPA file (app for iPhone) with Phonegap build. I think I have created certificates properly. I am getting below error while creating IPA from https://build.phonegap.com/

```
* ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED *
2019-01-11 23:05:19.215 xcodebuild[66036:58308081] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]
: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/37/x2444x712rnbshh_b1tlfwsm0000gp/T/Hagaholic_2019-01-11_23-05-19.214.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: Provisioning profile "Hagaholic distribution including push" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment entitlement.
Error Domain=IDEProfileQualificationErrorDomain Code=8 "Provisioning profile "Hagaholic distribution including push" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment entitlement." UserInfo={IDEProfileQualificationError_Profile=
<IDEEmbeddedProvisioningProfile 0x7fe9f10dc480: name: Hagaholic distribution including push, UUID: c63aaa2f-c497-4b87-ab3b-9c711daf2a68, teamName: Prachum Chanman, teamIdentifierPrefixes: (
                                2NJRT7L9MC
                                ), entitlements: {
                                "application-identifier" = "2NJRT7L9MC.com.pravelsolutions.hagaholic";
                                "aps-environment" = production;
                                "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers" =     (
                                );
                                "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers" =     (
                                );
                                "com.apple.developer.icloud-services" = "*";
                                "com.apple.developer.team-identifier" = 2NJRT7L9MC;
                                "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" =     (
                                );
                                "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" = "2NJRT7L9MC.*";
                                "get-task-allow" = 0;
                                "keychain-access-groups" =     (
                                "2NJRT7L9MC.*"
                                );
                                }, appIdentifierName: Hagaholic App, applicationIdentifierPrefixes: (
                                2NJRT7L9MC
                                ), dateCreated: 2019-01-12 06:08:07 +0000, dateExpired: 2020-01-12 05:42:29 +0000, certificateKind: 1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4, certificateSHA1Hashes: {(
                                92C0A518B8D8D02A56DC7DEDF52BDC2812964F81
                                )}, supportedUDIDs: {(
                                7cd2e1a71e3cd99b319e73603b4a577eeff79582,
                                c995976d26b1cd98b3d08db0ed77469504131604,
                                e21520179661f6024356446baa8cb0dff2029ba6,
                                50c50299034a129b4a33f130beabfc0a0ffeef72
                                )}, isUniversal: 0, isXcodeManaged: 0, platforms: {(
                                <DVTPlatform:0x7fe9ec611730:'com.apple.platform.watchos':
<DVTFilePath:0x7fe9ec6116b0:'/Applications/Xcode101.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform'>>,
  <DVTPlatform:0x7fe9ec60d940:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':
                               <DVTFilePath:0x7fe9ec60d8c0:'/Applications/Xcode101.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>
  )}, filePath: 
  <DVTFilePath:0x7fe9f1244600:'/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/production-ios-1547276652--42409.mobileprovision'>>, NSLocalizedDescription=Provisioning profile "Hagaholic distribution including push" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment entitlement., IDEProfileQualificationErrorMissingEntitlements=(
    "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment"
    )}
    * EXPORT FAILED *
    Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Hagaholic.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/private/project/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/private/project/build/device
```

Comment: I'd love to see the answer to this very frustrating problem! Creating the p12 and the provisional certs is hard enough without having to also figure out where the icloud thing is!